# v-if span not displaying when errors are filled vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2

so I have an error array in data and whenever user focuses out of an input it checks if its empty. If it is empty it add's an object to the error array like so:

```
[
    "0": {
        "product_name": {
            "message": "to polje je obvezno"
        },
        "barcode": {
            "message": "to polje je obvezno"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "barcode": {
            "message": "to polje je obvezno"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "product_name": {
            "message": "to polje je obvezno"
        }
    }
]
```

so the 0,1,2 stand for the index of the item because I have a v-for loop and then product_name or barcode stand for the input in that item/index.(component is at the end of the post if you need it). So now I am trying to display an error when product_name or barcode exists.

I am trying like this:

```
<span class="tooltip" 
      v-if="errors && errors[index] && errors[index]['product_name']" style="left: 5px">
  test123 (this is product_name error, above index is the current index in v-for so 0 or 1 or 2...)
</span>

<span class="tooltip" 
      v-if="errors && errors[index] && errors[index]['product_name']"style="left: 5px">
  test123 (this is barcode error, above index is the current index in v-for so 0 or 1 or 2...)
</span>
```

but it doesnt display the span

component:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in documentItems" :key="item.id">
  <td>{{index + 1}}.</td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <textarea v-model="item.barcode"
                @focusout="checkInput('barcode',index)"
                cols="15" rows="2"> 
      </textarea>
      <span v-if="errors && errors[index] && errors[index]['barcode']">
        test123
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <textarea v-model="item.product_name"
                @focusout="checkInput('product_name',index)"
                cols="15" rows="2"> 
      </textarea>
      <span v-if="errors && errors[index] && errors[index]['product_name']">
        test123
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT: is it possible that my checkInput is the problem? this is how I created errors:

```
   checkInput(name, itemIndex){
        if(this.documentItems[itemIndex][name] == null){
            this.errors[itemIndex][name] = { message: 'to polje je obvezno'}
        };
        //testing
        console.log(this.errors[itemIndex][name]); //works
        if(this.errors[1]['product_name']){
            console.log("yes"); //works
        }
    },
```

EDIT2:

the spans show if I define error object like so:

```
        errors: {
            0: {
                barcode: '',
                product_name: ''
            },
            1: {
                barcode: '',
                product_name: ''
            }
        },
```

but if I do it with a for loop span don't show (I made a for loop in method where I retrive all the documentItems and gets fired on mounted()):

```
for(var i = 0;i < response.data.documentItems[0].length;i++){
  this.errors[i] = {
    barcode: '',
    product_name: '',
  }
}
```

Comment: you could try `v-if="errors && errors[index] && errors[index]['product_name']"`. From the error, it seems like `errors[index]` is null, you cannot get `product_name` from `null`, hence that error

Comment: @RyanTeh no errors. but the span doesn't show

Comment: The span will not show if `errors` is null or `errors[index]` is null or `errors[index]['product_name']` is null. In this case, it seems like either `errors` is null or `errors[index]` is null. You should make sure `errors[index]` is not null.

simply adding `{{errors}}` at the bottom of the component to check contents of `errors`, or install the vue dev tools plugin

Comment: 1 more thing, make sure that `errors` object has all the properties before binding. Example: `data() => ({errors: {1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}})`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1xadrry the data is there but still no span. @RyanTeh

Comment: Does your console logged the message? And also maybe you can try to directly assign the error into existing errors instance like this `errors[index]['product_name'] = { message: ''}`, instead of using `_.merge`

Comment: @RyanTeh It does console log the message

Comment: So i changed the above to above code and gave errors object all the propetries before binding and it still doesnt show the span. console.log and vue dev tools still show all the data @RyanTeh

Comment: So if i manually add errors object data like above (1: {}, 2; {})... It works but when I use a for loop when mounted it doesn't work. The problem is that I dont know how many items there will be so I cannot manually add them. @RyanTeh

Comment: Just wanna confirm, are both spans not showing? I just checked the view you posted on your question, the span for barcode is checking for property product_name. I will try to create a project with your code and test it later.

Comment: Yeah copied your comment. I changed it in my project forgot to do i there. Both spans are not showing. They are showing if I define the error object. I will edit questions to show you what i mean. @RyanTeh

Comment: try this condition `v-if="errors?.[index]?.product_name"`

Comment: @Amaarrockz webpack compiles with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem roots in a vue reactivity caveat mentioned in their documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Vue will create proxy-like objects (a pattern similar to Observer using Object.defineProperty) for every field that is defined in your data function before anything runs, when you manually add fields using `this.foo = bar` (or something similar), if 'foo' key is not already available in your data field, vue will not make it reactive, hence it will not update your DOM when it changes.

You can achieve what you want in a couple of workarounds.

First way which also mentioned in their documentations is to create whole errors object with Object.assign or spread syntax and re-assign your field in data.

```
// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

This solution is similar to treating a field like its immutable

So you can fix your checkInput method with the following change:

```
   checkInput(name, itemIndex){
        if(this.documentItems[itemIndex][name] == null){
            const newErrorForName = { [name]: { message: 'to polje je obvenzo' }};
                this.errors = Object.assign({}, {...this.errors, [itemIndex]: newErrorForName })
        };
        //testing
        console.log(this.errors[itemIndex][name]); //works
        if(this.errors[1]['product_name']){
            console.log("yes"); //works
        }
    },
```

This is because vue cant understand manual object property add/delete.

Your second way is to use an array for errors instead of an object.
This is probably a better idea since your errors object is really an array.
it has fixed integer zero based indexes!